# How to make Django-Admin timezone aware?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to show all the datetime fields in databases in a different timezone than the default ('UTC') timezone only for the admin. I found a few proposed solutions which are more catered towards saving timezones per user. However I am looking for a solution which only solved the problem for the admin. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try this where field_date is the field that contain date in your model :

```
import datetime
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('show_admin_time',)
    def show_admin_time(self,request, obj):
        if request.user.is_superuser.field_date:
            formatfrom="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"
            formatto="%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S GMT"
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(obj.field_date,formatfrom).strftime(formatto)
        else:
            return obj.field_date

    show_admin_time.short_desc

description = 'time for admin'
```